# Tkinter typing animation

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a program that has a typing animation,

Here is  my reproducible example :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = "message"
num = 0
message = text[num]
label = Label(root,text=message)
label.pack()
def add() :
    global num
    num + 1
    leng = len(text)
    if num == leng :
        while True :
            num = leng
    label.configure(text=message)


root.after(1000, add)
root.mainloop()
```

It doesn't work and just shows the first letter

Comment: you get the first index number from your string, thats `m`. If you make from your `num=0` a `num=3` you become a `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please make descriptive variable names. Calling a variable `x` will not help others understand what they stand for.

Secondly, the way you used `root.after()` is not how it works. This piece of code should be in a function, which should have as the second parameter.

Finally, I removed the message variable because we can just increment the index value by 1.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = "message"
index = 0

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()

def add(a):
    global index
    if index < len(text):
        lab.config(text=lab.cget("text") + text[index])
        index += 1
    root.after(1000, add, root)


add('arg')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry for having bad variables, I can't think of stuff on the spot.